# Java. IntelliJ IDEA hotswap

Tags: java, build, intellij-idea, hotswap

I have a web project. I build it using maven(complete all stages in every module, then archiving each module to *.jar and then making war-file).
If I change one line of code in one class I need to run maven build script and it takes ~5 minutes.
How can I see my changes without building the whole application if I changes are within one class and one method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use IntelliJ IDEA for building your project and its [Artifacts](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/artifacts.html) in the **exploded** form, so that the classes can be reloaded with hotswap.

With such configuration you can [update your application](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/updating-a-running-java-ee-application.html) much faster. Also [check the tutorials](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/).

For even faster updates consider using [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/).

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using JRebel.  You will need to have a valid license.

You can also can try open source tools just take a look this hotswaping tutorial:

http://www.asjava.com/core-java/how-to-hotswap-java-code-into-jvm-redefinition-example/